# Issues while upgrading publisher server from 2011 to 2013

Tags: 2013-sp1, upgrade, installation

We are trying to upgrade our Tridion publisher server from Tridion SDL 2011 SP1 HR2 to Tridion SDL 2013 SP1.

First, the upgrade installer requests de `prerrequisites.msi` file and the installer does not let us to continue. In the filesystem cache we find out this file but after apply the MSI the installer request us the `postinstaller.msi` file. We also find out this file in the filesystem cache. After that, the installer request `ostinstallerhotfix.msi`.

We have tried to uninstall and after reinstall, but now the installer show an error and the installation process has not ended correctly:

> "product installation is failed. The error occured during the process. One or more problems caused the setup to fail".

In the log file we can see this exception:

> InitializeProperties:
>   config path: [installation bin path]\Tridion.ContentManager.config
>   Exception thrown by custom action:
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at
>   CSharpCustomActions.InitPropertiesCustomActions.SetUpgradeFrom2011(Session
>   session)    at
>   CSharpCustomActions.InitPropertiesCustomActions.InitializeProperties(Session
>   session)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object parameters, Object arguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.CustomActionProxy.InvokeCustomAction(Int32
>   sessionHandle, String entryPoint, IntPtr remotingDelegatePtr)
>   CustomAction InitializeProperties returned actual error code 1603
>   (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside
>   sandbox) Action ended 18:28:30: InitializeProperties. Return value 3.
>   Action ended 18:28:30: INSTALL. Return value 3.